# Add onclick event listener for all <img>s

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Pure "vanilla" javascript answers only.

I have a web page with a bunch of images, and I want to put some javascript at the bottom of the page that lets the user click on any image to enlarge it (I'm going to implement this with a modal).

Here is my attempt at binding a click to every <img>:

```js
function enlargeImage(imgElement){
    window.alert("Hi, I'm going to enlarge this image: "+imgElement.src);
    // create modal with <img src="imgElement.src">
}

var imageNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for (var i=0; i<imageNodes.length; i++)
{          
    imageNodes[i].addEventListener('click', enlargeImage(imageNodes[i]));
}
```

```css
img{
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Click on an image to enlarge it</h1>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WYlbunrdweQ/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/co1yhzb9fu0/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**What works about this**:

The image url gets transferred correctly.

**What's wrong about this**:

At page load it creates the modal, rather than when the image is clicked. It doesn't seem to actually bind any event-handlers either.

1. Why would it do that, if it's just binding the event (why is it calling the function)?
2. How do I make it work like I want to?

Comment: I still think it is valuable to not close this question because I could not find that particular question with my search terms. @GuyIncognito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for the eventlistener a callback function which calls enlarge with `this`as parameter.

```js
function enlargeImage(imgElement){
    window.alert("Hi, I'm going to enlarge this image: "+imgElement.src);
    // create modal with <img src="imgElement.src">
}

var imageNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imageNodes.length; i++)
{          
    imageNodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        enlargeImage(this);
    });
}
```

```css
img {width:100px;}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Click on an image to enlarge it</h1>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WYlbunrdweQ/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/co1yhzb9fu0/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generic handler instead of binding a seperate handler to each img seems to work.

```js
window.onclick = function(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.tagName=="IMG"){
    window.alert("Hi, im going to enlarge this image: "+clickEvent.target.src);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your onclick-function will be called every click on the whole webside so perhaps my solution with binding the eventlistener directly to the IMG should be the better solution.